# OEM Wheels for a 2012 Odyssey

Tags: honda, wheels, odyssey

I have a 2012 Honda Odyssey. I'm having trouble finding OEM wheels for it. the spec calls for 7J x 17 ET50  5 lug x 120. Are there other Honda model wheels that I can use?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

[This site sells factory wheels](http://www.originalwheels.com/honda-wheels/odyssey2012rims.php)

[Town Fair Tire](https://www.townfairtire.com/) can get OEM and/or OEM-Style Reproductions.

Junk Yard/Salvage Yards likely will have some available, and some have their inventory online now.

Dealers should be able to order them. Looks like Honda's Part Site has a [Wheel Section](https://parts.sonshonda.com/cars/Honda/0/Odyssey/Wheels--Tires/Odyssey-parts.html)

[Based on the forums, lots of folks run MDX wheels.](http://www.odyclub.com/forums/54-2011-2017-odyssey/163009-4th-gen-odyssey-mdx-wheels.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find, it appears they used that wheel size on the 2008 thru 2017 Odyssey models. I can't seem to find any accurate information about other models that have that rim size.

Source: https://www.wheel-size.com/

It is important to note that your wheel has a specific offset (ET50). Try not to stray too far away from that if selecting wheel from a different model.